# golang json unmarshall to struct whose field value unexpected

Tags: json, go

I have a data type as the following, which converts and store JSON data for bussiness. For efficiency, I reuse the same variable in each unmarshall. but field named Child content unexpected after first unmarshall.

**data type**

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
 Age   int    `json:"age"`
 Name  string `json:"name"`
 Child []int  `json:"child"`
}
```

**code**

```
package main

import (
 "encoding/json"
 "fmt"
)

type AutoGenerated struct {
 Age   int    `json:"age"`
 Name  string `json:"name"`
 Child []int  `json:"child"`
}

func main() {
 jsonStr1 := `{"age": 14,"name": "potter", "child":[1,2,3]}`
 a := AutoGenerated{}
 json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr1), &a)
 aa := a.Child
 fmt.Println(aa)
 jsonStr2 := `{"age": 12,"name": "potter", "child":[3,4,5,7,8,9]}`
 json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr2), &a)
 fmt.Println(aa)
}
```

**expect output**

```
[1,2,3]
[3,4,5,7,8,9]
```

**actual output**

```
[1,2,3]
[3,4,5]
```

**several attempts**

On the contrary, I replaced type *AutoGenerated* with slice and gave the corresponding JSON, everything worked as expect.

Can anyone explain that? why length is limited in the unexpected case?

Comment: Could you try doing `aa := a.Child` again after the second unmarshal. My assumption right now is that the slice that `aa` is referencing is a slice of 3 ints, and the second unmarshal created a new slice reference, i.e. `aa` is now a stale reference.

Comment: You unmarshal into a but print aa.

Answer (score 3):

### The explanation

You have

```golang
type AutoGenerated struct {
  Child []int
}
```

Then you do

```golang
a := AutoGenerated{}                 // (1)

jsonStr1 := `{"age": 14,"name": "potter", "child":[1,2,3]}`
json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr1), &a) // (2)

aa := a.Child                        // (3)
fmt.Println(aa)

jsonStr2 := `{"age": 12,"name": "potter", "child":[3,4,5,7,8,9]}`
json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr2), &a) // (4)

fmt.Println(aa)
```

So, what happens:

1. You create a variable, `a`, of type `AutoGenerated` which is initialized to the zero value for its type.

   Because of that, its `Child` field, which is a slice, is initialized to the zero value for a slice which, among other things, means having no backing array.
2. You unmarshal a JSON document into `a`, and an array `[1, 2, 3]` from that documnent got unmarshaled into `Child`.

   This made the slice allocate a backing array of enough capacity to hold the three element. Please note this.
3. You *copy* the slice value from the field `Child` into the variable `aa`.

   A slice in Go is a `struct` of three fields: the capacity, the length and *a pointer to* (an address of) the backing array holding the slice's contents.
   This is what is copied when you copy a slice value.
   Note that the backing array is not copied; only its address.
4. You unmarshal another JSON document into `a`.
   This time, a longer array gets unmarshaled into the slice in the `Child` field of `a`.

   Since it contains twice as much elements `Child` held before unmarshaling, the code which did the unmarshaling had to *reallocate* the backing array of the slice: let's cite the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal):

   > To unmarshal a JSON array into a slice, Unmarshal resets the slice length to zero and then appends each element to the slice. As a special case, to unmarshal an empty JSON array into a slice, Unmarshal replaces the slice with a new empty slice.

   This time, unmarshaling went like this:

   1. The length of the slice was reset to 0 (this is typically done with reslicing the original slice, like in `s = s[:0]`).
      This retained the slice's backing array able to hold 3 elements.
   2. The unmarshaling code placed the fist three elements into the slice.
   3. To place the fourth and the following elements, there were no room in the old backing array, so the `append` operation reallocated the array and copied the already marshaled three elements over to the new array.

      Reallocation made a new fresh backing array and assigned its address to the slice value held in the `Child` field.

      *Nothing was done* to the *slice value* in the `aa` variable: it continued to point to the old backing array.
      The array's *contents* did change, but that's not due to reallocation: it merely detached the old array from the slice in `Child`.

I would also note that the documentation (cited above) guarantees that if the slice to unmarshal an array to is initialized, it will be (re-)used up to its capacity.
Hence if you know in advance the maximum length of the arrays you're about to unmarshal, you could preallocate the slice's space and be guaranteed each unmarshall will reuse the slice's array, and the situation from the question won't happen.

On the other hand, since there's no way to know the length of the array to unmarshal from a JSON document without actually scanning it to its end, you cannot *guarantee* no reallocation will ever happen.

### Further reading

- ["Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'"](https://blog.golang.org/slices).
- ["Go Slices: usage and internals"](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro).

Comment: the very detailed answer, but ```Nothing had happened to the slice value in the variable```  doesn't mean the backing array of the old silce pointing to not changed, it became into ```3,4,5```, does it?

Comment: Yes, you're correct: the second unmarshal first consumed the capacity of the original backing array, which was 3, then reallocated the backing array and copied those three elements over. Thanks; I stand corrected. Let me update the answer.

Comment: @cacojr, updated. Thanks again. Note that while it's indeed bad for me to not have thought through this detail, the sentence «Nothing had happened to the slice value in the variable» is 100% correct nonetheless: the contents of the backing array _attached_ to that slice is changed, but the slice itself does not: neither its length, nor capacity nor the pointer to the backing array—just the data which can be "accessed through" that slice.

Comment: yep, it's totally correct that the data, or memory, in the other words,  held by the field of Child not changed. But most of the time it requires more details to figure out what happened under the hood.
The answer u last update did a real good job